# "If two threads are using Pulse and Wait to interact, this could result in a deadlock."

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deadlock, monitor

Basically the load() is for the producer(there's one and only one dispatcher thread that loads the _tickQueue) and the Unload is for the consumer(there's one and only one dedicated thread executing the function). _tickQueue is a regular queue protected by a lock(I'm using itself as the argument to lock()). Surprisingly, it caused deadlock.

```
    public void Load(Tick tick)
    {
        lock (_tickQueue)
        {
            while (_tickQueue.Count >= CapSize)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(_tickQueue);
            }

            _tickQueue.Enqueue(tick);
            if (!_receivedTickCounts.ContainsKey(tick.Underlier))
            {
                _receivedTickCounts.Add(tick.Underlier, 0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Received {1} ticks for {0}", tick.Underlier, ++_receivedTickCounts[tick.Underlier]);
            Monitor.Pulse(_tickQueue);
        }
    }

    private void Unload()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Tick tick;
                lock (_tickQueue)
                {
                    while (_tickQueue.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_tickQueue);
                    }

                    tick = _tickQueue.Dequeue();
                    Monitor.Pulse(_tickQueue);
                }

                Persist(tick);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The comment in the title was found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

My understanding of the "Important" paragraph is: Monitor class not maintaining state (in the way ResetEvent does) implies deadlock. A specific example was given: when two threads interact using Pulse and Wait, if one thread pulses when the other thread is not on the wait queue, then deadlock happens.

Can someone SPECIFICALLY(e.g. give a scenario for deadlock to happen) point out where I did wrong in my program? I don't see any scenario that can possibly lead to deadlock.
Thanks.

===================EDIT====================

Specifically, I'm interested to know why the following coding pattern for monitor suddenly doesn't work - must be related to the monitor implementation in .net?

```
lock
    while(wait condition is met)
    {
        wait()
    }

    // critical section: doing work

    signal();// or broadcast()
unlock
```

Comment: Why not use `BlockingCollection<T>`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SimonSvensson Hi Simon. Thanks for the comment. I'm sure there're a million ways to get the task done. Would like to hear why my way didn't work. Let's think of this as a technical exercise with which I can learn more about threading.

Comment: Please find a more meaningful title to your question!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are imposing an un-ending wait upon both methods.  You are surrounding your Monitor method calls with While loops continually checking a condition.    For certain values of CapSize and _tickQueue.Count, both of your Load() and Unload() methods will be forever waiting.  What isn't evident here is the value of CapSize, is it constant, or does it change? Is _tickQueue thread-safe?

What if we reach an error on tick = _tickQueue.Dequeue(); in Unload(), _tickQueue.Count reaches 0, and the Load() method was Waiting()'ing?  Load() will be waiting forever.

I would avoid having your consumer method Pulse to notify that Producer method it's ready for more work.  Your consumer should only be waiting when there is no more work for it to do (queue is empty).  Your Producer would be better suited controlling it's own work schedule, and pulsing the consumer when new work has been queued.  Why not put the Producer on a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

In the end, I believe the supplied code simply provides too many points of failure.  Could I suggest an alternate implementation?  This uses the thread-safe ConcurrentQueue collection and eliminates the discussed issues.

```
public class StackOverflowMonitorExample
{

    ConcurrentQueue<Tick> _tickQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Tick>();
    object locker = new object();
    bool stopCondition = false;

    public void Load(Tick tick)
    {
        _tickQueue.Enqueue(tick);

        lock (locker)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(locker);
        }

    }

    private void Unload()
    {
        while (!stopCondition)
        {
            try
            {
                Tick nextWorkItem = null;

                _tickQueue.TryDequeue(out nextWorkItem);

                if (nextWorkItem != null)
                {
                    Persist(nextWorkItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(locker);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This eliminates the large locking sections, and removes most of the signals between the consumer and producer.  The Producer will only ever add new items to the queue, and Pulse() to notify that new work is available.  The Consumer will loop and continue to work as long as items remain in the queue, and stop condition has not been met.  If queue count reaches 0, then the consumer will wait for new queue entries.